# Unable to run multiple UPDATE with BigQuery via Python SDK

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm working on an ETL with Apache Beam and Dataflow using Python and I'm using BigQuery as a database/datawarehouse.

The ETL basically performs some processing then updates data that is already in BigQuery. Since there is no update transform in Apache Beam, I had to use the BigQuery SDK and write my own UPDATE query, and map it to each row.

The queries work fine when done sequentially, but when I use multiple workers, I get the following error:

```py
{'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'message': 'Could not serialize access to table my_table due to concurrent update'}
```

I made sure that the same row is never accessed/updated concurrently (a row is basically an id, and each id is unique), I've also tried to run the same code with a simple Python script without Beam/Dataflow, and I still got the same error when I started using multiple threads instead of one.

Has anyone got the same problem using BigQuery SDK ? And do you have any suggestions to avoid that problem ?

Comment: Hello Sami, it's a batch job ?

Comment: Yes it's a batch job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better from your `Beam` `Dataflow` job to `append` the data.
`Bigquery` is more `append` oriented and the `BigueryIO` in `Beam` is adapted for `append` operation.

If you have an orchestrator like `Cloud Composer/Airflow` or `Cloud Workflows`, you can deduplicate the data in `batch` mode with the following steps :

- Create a staging and final tables
- Your orchestrator truncates your staging table
- Your orchestrator runs your Dataflow job
- Dataflow job reads your data
- Dataflow job writes the result in append mode to Bigquery in the `staging` table
- Your orchestrator run a task with a `merge` query with `Bigquery` between the staging and final tables. The merge query allows to insert or update the line in the final table if the element exists.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax?hl=en#merge_statement

Example of a merge query :

```sql
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think this "staging" table should be created and deleted dynamically or should it already exist before the job starts ?
Also, in our case, the rows always exist in the "final" table, so there would be no "WHEN NOT MATCHED" statement, is this problematic ?

Comment: I thinks the tables should exist before the job starts (manually or with a tool like `Terraform`), it's better to control this with an `infra as code` tool instead of let `Airflow` or `Dataflow` job create the tables.  For the `WHEN NOT MATCHED`, it's not problematic, you can even remove this statement if you want, but maybe you need to have the `insert` for the first time the line is received.

Answer (score 1):

I had a use case where I had a BQ table that was containing around 150K records, and I needed to update its content monthly (which means around 100K `UPDATE` and couple of thousands `APPEND`.

When I designed my Beam/Dataflow job to update the records with the BQ python API library, I fall in Quota issues (limited number of updated) as well as the concurrency issue.

I had to change the approach my pipeline was working with, from reading the BQ table and updating the record, to process the BQ table, update what needs to be updated, and append what's new, and save to a new BQ table.

Once the job is successfully finished with no error, you can replace the old one with the new created table.

Comment: As of March 3, 2020, GCP has done away with this limit apparently . Was it before that date ? See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery

Comment: `Your project can run up to 100 concurrent interactive queries`. Dataflow jobs usually goes with parallel workers (up to 1000 workers), which will make you fall under the quotas limit

Answer (score 1):

GCP mentions:

> Running two mutating DML statements concurrently against a table will
> succeed as long as the two statements don’t modify data in the same
> partition. Two jobs that try to mutate the same partition may
> sometimes experience concurrent update failures.

And then :

> BigQuery now handles such failures automatically. To do this, BigQuery
> will restart the job.

Can this retry mechanism be a solution at all ? Anyone to elaborate on this?

Source: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery